# Why is the SD card mounted as read-only on PC when shared from HTC Desire HD via USB?

Tags: sd-card, htc-desire-hd, usb-connection-mode

I just discovered that the SD card is now read-only when I use "disk drive" connection on the phone.

Why do I have to do in order to be able to write on the SD card from the PC?

I mention that the phone is rooted and is using the latest version of 2.3 available for HTC Desire HD (original rom).

Answer (score 1):

It may sound really strange but the real issue was the corporate policy of mounting the the unencrypted drives as read-only. This is specific to BitLocker and there is a registry workaround available.

Answer (score 0):

From what i have found on the internets is that there are a lot of people that have had issues like this with the Desire HD.

They all said that either formatting the sdcard in Windows, or even using Windows 7 to "Verify Errors" solved the issue.

Before you format, you can copy all the content off the sdcard, and then place it back after formatting.